# Class.forName android NoClassDefFoundError -> ClassNotFoundException

Tags: java, android, class, reflection

I have program and i use below code to load classes
android.media.RemoteControlClient
android.media.RemoteControlClient.MetadataEditor ****gives the error
android.media.MediaMetadataRetriever

every class loads except one, only one line gives the error others work fine

```
try{
        mRemoteControlClass=Class.forName("android.media.RemoteControlClient");   

        //this gives the error
        MetadataEditorC=Class.forName("android.media.RemoteControlClient.MetadataEditor");

        MediaMetadataRetrieverC=Class.forName("android.media.MediaMetadataRetriever");

        Log.e("RemoteControlClient", "Succesfully Set Metadata");
        }catch(Exception e){e.printStackTrace();
            Log.e("RemoteControlClient", "ERROR Set Metadata");}
```

this is the stack trace

```
08-17 16:17:17.621: W/System.err(1771): java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: android.media.RemoteControlClient.MetadataEditor
08-17 16:17:17.621: W/System.err(1771):     at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
08-17 16:17:17.621: W/System.err(1771):     at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:217)
08-17 16:17:17.621: W/System.err(1771):     at com.SmoothApps.iSenseMusic.MyRemoteControlClient.updatemetadata(MyRemoteControlClient.java:94)
08-17 16:17:17.621: W/System.err(1771):     at com.SmoothApps.iSenseMusic.iSenseMusic.setNotify(iSenseMusic.java:296)
08-17 16:17:17.621: W/System.err(1771):     at com.SmoothApps.iSenseMusic.iSenseMusic.onStartCommand(iSenseMusic.java:421)
08-17 16:17:17.621: W/System.err(1771):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleServiceArgs(ActivityThread.java:2656)
08-17 16:17:17.621: W/System.err(1771):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1900(ActivityThread.java:141)
08-17 16:17:17.621: W/System.err(1771):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1331)
08-17 16:17:17.621: W/System.err(1771):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
08-17 16:17:17.621: W/System.err(1771):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
08-17 16:17:17.621: W/System.err(1771):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5039)
08-17 16:17:17.621: W/System.err(1771):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-17 16:17:17.621: W/System.err(1771):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
08-17 16:17:17.621: W/System.err(1771):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
08-17 16:17:17.621: W/System.err(1771):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
08-17 16:17:17.621: W/System.err(1771):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
08-17 16:17:17.621: W/System.err(1771): Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: android/media/RemoteControlClient/MetadataEditor
08-17 16:17:17.621: W/System.err(1771):     ... 16 more
08-17 16:17:17.621: W/System.err(1771): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: android.media.RemoteControlClient.MetadataEditor
08-17 16:17:17.621: W/System.err(1771):     at java.lang.VMClassLoader.loadClass(Native Method)
08-17 16:17:17.621: W/System.err(1771):     at java.lang.BootClassLoader.findClass(ClassLoader.java:765)
08-17 16:17:17.621: W/System.err(1771):     at java.lang.BootClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:825)
08-17 16:17:17.621: W/System.err(1771):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:461)
08-17 16:17:17.621: W/System.err(1771):     ... 16 more
08-17 16:17:17.621: W/System.err(1771): Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: [generic]
08-17 16:17:17.621: W/System.err(1771):     ... 1 more
```

if i try a different approach then things work, but it is not ideal coding or cpu friendly, i have to load all the sub classes of the super class and then check the names and it work as i coded below(i don't know why the simple process i used above is not working)

```
Class[] cls=mRemoteControlClass.getDeclaredClasses();
            for(int i=0;i<cls.length;i++){
                //Log.e("CLASS "+(i+1),cls[i].getName());
                if(cls[i].getName().contains("MetadataEditor"))
                MetadataEditorC=cls[i];
            }
```

what i can guess is that thenclass MetaDataEditor doesn't have a Class Definition, so it can't be loaded. But by the other method i can load it.

I hope there is some simple way to load the class, i am not much familiar with the java class loading, please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this notation (see `$`):

```
MetadataEditorC=Class.forName(
        "android.media.RemoteControlClient$MetadataEditor");
```

This is usually used for a reference to an inner class.

Comment: It worked when i tried again after your answer. I don't know why it didn't work when i tried earlier(i probably made some error). Thanks for the quick reply, this is great.
Thank you sir